# Send public html file or content in response to a function

Tags: node.js

I'm getting started with firebase, firebase functions are returning a string which is a html format. I couldn't find any way to reply with html file which is a public html file or at least redirect to it(without rewrites).

I'm new nodejs and stuff. I googled and found few other modules/frameworks are using this.

```
var fs = require('fs');
pp.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    var html = fs.readFileSync('./html/test.html', 'utf8')
    res.render('test', { html: html })
    // or res.send(html)
})
```

Comment: FWIW your question has absolutely nothing to do with Firebase, more express

Comment: Please read my question I found the code of other framework. I mean I'm talking about firebase. @James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with this solution and works fine.

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    var path = require('path');
    var site_root = path.resolve(__dirname+'/..');
    exports.blog = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        res.status(200).sendFile(site_root+'/app/index.html') 
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just have to send html path with "sendFile" method like this :

```
    pp.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
       res.sendFile('html/test.html');
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Use of `render` won't work without the appropriate configuration.

Comment: please read my question I mentioned that the above code is from other framework or something I related my solution to it thats it

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use `render` out the box, `render` works with different types of renderers (or at minimum needs configured via the `view engine`).

In your case however, if the file is static and you know the path then you can use [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

```
// configure static path (not necessary to render the page but useful if you have other static assets)
pp.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'html'));
// serve HTML
pp.get('/test', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'html', 'test.html')));
```

Comment: please read my question I mentioned that the above code is from other framework or something I related my solution to it thats it

Comment: Actual code.

`const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 res.status(200).send(`
      'hello world'
    `);
});`

Changed  working.

`const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const hours = (new Date().getHours() % 12) + 1 // london is UTC + 1hr;
  res.status(200).sendFile('/home/vam/brio_blog/app/one.html')
});`

I cannot use this path in production, how can i fix this instead of using __dirname I need __roordir kind of.